# How can I make my custom item increase digging speed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am currently trying to implement a custom crafting recipe in which it will place a dropper with a stone pickaxe with faster digging attributes. I was looking at [the Attributes page on the Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Attribute?oldid=1529760#Modifiers), but I couldn't find any modifiers to increase digging speed.

```
execute at @p run setblock ~ ~-1 ~ dropper{Items:[{Slot:4b,id:"minecraft:stone_pickaxe",Count:1b,tag:{Unbreakable:1,display:{Name:'[{"text":"test pick","italic":false}]'},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"effect.digSpeed",Name:"effect.digSpeed",Amount:10,Operation:2}]}}]} replace
```

Is there any specific attribute to increase digging speed?
If there isn't, I'm hoping for maybe an invisible potion effect when the item is held.

Comment: Efficiency enchantment?

Comment: Yeah, that attribute just doesn't work. Many don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly that is not a thing however, you could use the efficiency enchantment like so:

```
execute at @p run setblock ~ ~-1 ~ dropper{Items:[{Slot:4b,id:"minecraft:stone_pickaxe",Count:1b,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:efficiency",lvl:200}],Unbreakable:1,display:{Name:'[{"text":"test pick","italic":false}]]'}}}]} replace
```

It will put a pickaxe with efficiency level 200 in the dropper

Comment: You could also additionally give a player holding that specific pickaxe a Haste effect by detecting the pickaxe in a repeating command, but since Efficiency goes up to level 32767, that's probably not needed.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yeah, I was hoping to make it enchantable, and that's why I wanted something other than an already implemented enchant. I'll try your idea Fabian. Thanks!